# How to post the form tag action value in ejs?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

is there any know that?

I'm testing some javascript as follows

```js
function mem_join_next() {
  if (document.mem_join.email.value == "") {
    alert("please input your email ID");
    document.mem_join.email.focus();
    return;
  }

  document.mem_join.submit();
}
```

```html
<form name="mem_join" action="/join_step_3" method="post">

  <div class="col-xs-12 id">
    <p><span>EMAIL</span><span class="star">*</span>
    </p>
    <input name='email' class="email1" type="text" style="IME-MODE: disabled" size="11">@
    <input class="email2" type="text">
    <div class="email-check">email_check</div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-6 next" align="right">
    <a onClick="mem_join_next()" style="cursor:pointer">
      <img src="/page_imgs/member_img/btn-next.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
```

It's code what i want to run.

But when It is processing, the screen come out the 404 not found error.

even it is right route.

I think the post is not working

cause if i go straight way to single URL address(`localhost/join_step_3`) , the screen come out the `/join_step_3` address screen.

but if i go From `join_step_2` form next button TO `join_step_3`, It is `404 not found` please hell me! GOD PROGRAMMERS!

Comment: if you typed and the url came, then are you sure the page accepts post. that said, it shudnt give 404 but 405 if that was the error

Comment: I'm sure the url is right.
cause when I press the url enter agian, it's working. but when going to url from join_step_2 to join_step_3, it's not working.

Comment: Just asking if you change `method="post"` to `get`, is it showing the same error?

Comment: oh ok you mean method = "get" Oh!! it's working thanks!!!!

Comment: cud u upvote if the answer was helpful :D thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you directly typed the url and it worked means the page at `localhost/join_step_3` worked using `GET`, because the browser url uses the `GET Method`.

So, it is quite possible that your `localhost/join_step_3` doesn't support `POST Method`. Therefore, either add the post support on the page depending on the server-side scripting you use, or change `method="post"` to `method="get"` in your client html.